# WASAPI: Getting the actual wave format a device is initialized with

Tags: c++, audio, wasapi

I need to programmatically get a wave format (`WAVEFORMATEX` structure) of the initialized WASAPI rendering audio device. `IAudioClient::GetMixFormat` doesn't fit in this case, because `IAudioClient::Initialize` can be called with another format (not equal to the mix format).
When the device is activated and initialized, what other methods of `IAudioClient` or `IAudioRenderClient` (or others?) can I call to programmatically get the ***actual*** wave format of it?